# Как «симулировать» наведение мыши на строку в таблице?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Есть две таблицы. При наведении мыши на строку в одной из них, нужно "подсвечивать" или "выделять" строку и во второй.

Я написал следующий код:

```
$('tr').mouseenter(function() {

    $("tr").removeClass("active");

    var myTr = $(this);
    var myTable = myTr.closest('table');

    var oppTable;
    if ($(myTable).hasClass('fixed-column')) {
        oppTable = $(myTable).next();
    } else {
        oppTable = $(myTable).prev();
    }

    var oppTableRow = oppTable.find('tr:eq(' + (myTr.index() + 1) + ')');
    oppTableRow.addClass("active");
});
```

Он отлично работает в связке с bootstrap'ом, НО только для тех строк, которые не имеют ни какого класса. Пример строки для которой код работает:

```
<tr> ... </tr>
```

Для такой строки:

```
<tr class="danger"> ... </tr>
```

Код уже работать не будет. Почему?

**UPD**

По просьбе, выкладываю стили `active` и `danger`. Они взяты из bootstrap.css:

```
.table > thead > tr > td.warning,
.table > tbody > tr > td.warning,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.warning,
.table > thead > tr > th.warning,
.table > tbody > tr > th.warning,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.warning,
.table > thead > tr.warning > td,
.table > tbody > tr.warning > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.warning > td,
.table > thead > tr.warning > th,
.table > tbody > tr.warning > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.warning > th {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.warning:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.warning:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.warning:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .warning,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.warning:hover > th {
  background-color: #faf2cc;
}

.table > thead > tr > td.active,
.table > tbody > tr > td.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.active,
.table > thead > tr > th.active,
.table > tbody > tr > th.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.active,
.table > thead > tr.active > td,
.table > tbody > tr.active > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > td,
.table > thead > tr.active > th,
.table > tbody > tr.active > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > th {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

**UPD 2**

Пытаясь разобраться я узнал, что CSS поддерживает выбор элементов с несколькими классами. Я попытался написать следующее правило:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.danger.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.danger.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger.active > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .danger.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger.active > th {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Для следующего HTML кода:

```
<tr class="danger active"></tr>
```

Но к сожалению, это не сработало =(

Comment: выведете переменную `oppTableRow ` и посмотрите, чем она равна в каждом из двух случаев ( с классом, без )

Comment: `tr.danger.active` в случае наведения и `tr.danger` - если не наведено. Вроде как, все верно, нет?

Comment: tr td.active {background:#ff0000;} должно работать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var oppTableRow = oppTable.find('tr:eq(' + (myTr.index() + 1) + ')');
```

В переменной находится строка во второй таблице, которую нужно подсветить.

**Почему может не работать**

- `oppTableRow` пустая и не содержит ни каких элементов
- Другие классы у `tr` ( например `danger`) перекрывают стили

Проверьте второй `tr` в инспекторе браузера, применяется ли к нему класс, и проверьте переменную `oppTableRow` при наведении на первый tr

**UPD**

Если все таки классы у `tr` перебивают стили у класса `active` - то расположить `active` ниже классов `tr`, либо поставить более приоритетный селектор

```
/* классы для tr */

.active {
    /* ... */
}
```

или

```
tr.class {}

table tr.active { /* вроде бы селектор приоритетней чем просто tr */ }
```

Comment: Первый вариант исключен.Вы написали, что danger может перекрывать стили. Если так, то как с этим бороться?

Comment: Либо прописать для активного элемента стили `inline`, либо поместить класс `active` ниже других возможных классов у `tr` + приоритетней селекторы для стилей расставить

Comment: Перенес все определения: `tr.active` в самый конец файла - все равно  стили классов `danger` и `warning` перекрывают стили `active`. Если честно, я CSS сегодня первый раз правлю, возможно я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: Добавьте тогда в вопрос стили, что бы можно было увидеть их( как `active` так и `danger` классов )

Comment: Добавил в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался! Проблема была действительно в перекрытии стилей классов. Я написал следующий CSS-код:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.info.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.info.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info.active > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .info.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info.active > th {
    background-color: #c4e3f3 !important;
}

.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.danger.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.danger.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger.active > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .danger.active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger.active > th {
    background-color: #ebcccc !important;
}
```

Теперь все работает идеально. Для того, чтобы строка была "подсвечена" так, как будто я на нее навел мышку, достаточно добавить класс `active`. Это мне и было нужно. Спасибо ThisMan за наводку!